# Is it safe to assume a wall is not load bearing if the studs are on 24” centers?

Tags: carpentry, load-bearing

I am looking at remodel options in a 2003 built townhome.

In considering which walls may be load bearing is it safe to say that when walls are interior and have studs in 24” centers they are not load bearing?

Or is 24” spacing code compliant with both load bearing and non load bearing walls?

Comment: Can be bearing to code. https://www.protradecraft.com/article/best-way-frame-less-wood-more-thought

Comment: Are they 2x4 or 2x6 walls? 2x6 on 24" can very easily be load-bearing

Comment: `is it safe to assume` .... that can never be answered `yes`

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel 2x4

Comment: @jsotola  true dat!

Comment: likely, but "usually the case" != "safe to say".

Answer (score 2):

Nope...2x4 studs at 24” on center can support roof plus ceiling up to 10’ height.  2x6 studs at 24” on center can support one floor plus roof plus ceiling up to 10’ height without analysis. (See ICC Table R602.3(5).)

Without analysis means an architect or structural engineer could provide calculations to prove that they could be further apart, support more load, or be taller than specified in the Table.

Comment: @Kris Per ICC code, it can either be load bearing, or non-load bearing wall. It is better to check with an engineer, if you want to alter it.

Comment: Additional note -  For the vertical stud, ICC requires lateral blocking/bracing 4' oc maximum; and the roof span is limited to 32', for a wall, with 2x4 studs @24" oc, to be used for load bearing,